# Render JSX template in reverse order on add more click in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to add a child component on action of a click.

I am getting the desired result but the template is getting rendered below to the previous one.

```
const [branchArray, setBranchArray] = useState([]);

const createBranches = () => {
  let branchRef = createRef();
  setBranchArray([...branchArray, { branchRef: branchRef }]);
};

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom maring={10}>
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        color="primary"
        onClick={createBranches}
      >
        Add Branch Address <AddIcon />
      </Button>
    </Typography>

    {branchArray.map((branchObj, i) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom maring={10}>
            Branch Address {i + 1}
          </Typography>

          <BillingAddress
            ref={branchObj.branchRef}
            saveAddress={branchAddress}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

I want the opposite behaviour. On click the new form Fragment should be rendered on top of the previously rendered template.

Answer (score 0):

So shouldn't you just move it up like this:

```
const [branchArray, setBranchArray] = useState([]);

const createBranches = () => {
let branchRef = createRef();
setBranchArray([...branchArray, {branchRef: branchRef}]);

return branchArray.map((branchObj, i) => (
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>

            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom maring={10}>
              Branch Address {i + 1}
            </Typography>

            <BillingAddress
                ref={branchObj.branchRef} 
                saveAddress={branchAddress} 
            ></BillingAddress> 

          </React.Fragment>
        );

      ))
}

return (
 <React.Fragment>
  <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom maring={10}>
    <Button variant="outlined" size="small" color="primary" onClick= 
    {createBranches()}>
      Add Branch Address <AddIcon />
    </Button>
 </Typography>
 </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Plus you should really extract the logic from returning the jsx with branches `branchArray.map()` to its own function and then call it from inside of the jsx and not the `createBranches`.

Comment: Yes, this can be done but this doesnt solve the problem of rendering the template in reverse order. Also it throws an error - Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.